# check if two ZFS filesystems are identical

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I would like to verify that two ZFS filesystems (in this case on different pools) are identical. Is there a best  practice way to do this?

Comment: It would be highly unlikely, unless you cloned them. If you meant to check file and directories, try the diff tool

Answer (score 3):

If checking the contents of the filesystem and not the filesystem itself, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ#4997724

Answer (score 1):

You can compare them in different manners:

- for a **bit-for-bit comparison**, you can `md5` the physical backing devices. This assumes identical pool setup/layout, and no changes at all in the filesystem (ie: even seemingly insignificant changes, as small as a single `atime` difference). In practice, the chances to usefully bit-per-bit compare two zpool are very, very low.
- for a **filesystem-level comparison**, you can send both zfs filesystem to two different files, and `md5` them. Again, any small changes in one of the filesystem and you are screwed.
- for **content comparison**, you can `md5` any files on both filesystem and compare/diff the results. This is going to be the most flexible and useful (but slower) method to compare the two filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say `zfsdiff`, but that's only for snapshots. I'd just do a dry run of `rsync` between the filesystems if I were you.